# Xaml islands - 3rd party controls

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, telerik, xaml-islands

Following tutorials such as [Host UWP XAML Controls in desktop apps (XAML Islands)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/xaml-islands), I can add Microsoft UWP controls to WPF apps.  Based on the doco, it appears third party and custom UWP controls can also be used like this.

What do I need to do to add 3rd party UWP controls to wpf desktop apps? Specifically, I am interested in using Telerik's open source [UI for UWP controls](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/Introduction-uwp).

I have added the Telerik nuget package to my uwp project, and have the XamlHost in my WPF project but where I try to code a control the ui instead shows a message `Cannot create control of type Telerik.UI.XamlControls.<ControlName>`.

Can someone show the way to use (for e.g.) the [Telerik UWP Rad Gauge](https://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui/gauge) in a WPF desktop app with XAML Islands?